# Como fazer uma consulta utilizando SUM corretamente SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
 SELECT
  YEAR(NFDtEmis) AS 'Ano',
  MONTH(NFDtEmis) AS 'Mes',
  ItProduto AS 'Produto',
  SUM(ItQtde) AS 'Quantidade total'
FROM NotasItens
INNER JOIN NotasFiscais
  ON NFEmpresa = ItEmpresa
  AND NFNumero = ItNfNumero
  AND NFTIPO = ItTipo
INNER JOIN Tributos
  ON TribEmpresa = ItEmpresa
  AND TribCodigo = ItCFO
WHERE ItEmpresa = '03'
AND ItProduto = 'JKIT'
AND NFDtEmis >= '2016-04-01'
AND NFDtEmis <= '2017-07-31'
AND NFStatus = 'I'
AND NFTipo = 'S'
AND NFEmpresa = '03'
AND UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(TribTpCFOP))) = 'VENDA'
GROUP BY YEAR(NFDtEmis),
         MONTH(NFDtEmis),
         ItProduto,
         ItQtde
ORDER BY YEAR(NFDtEmis), MONTH(NFDtEmis)
```

Eu escrevi na idéia de trazer a quantidade total vendidada do produto "JKit" para cada mês a partir de Abril/2016, porém eu não sei porque, ele está repetindo o mês, ao invês de somar tudo.
Acredito que possa estar errado o `SUM()`

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, tu acabou colocando a quantidade ( `ItQtde` ) no group by.

```
SELECT
  YEAR(NFDtEmis) AS 'Ano',
  MONTH(NFDtEmis) AS 'Mes',
  ItProduto AS 'Produto',
  SUM(ItQtde) AS 'Quantidade total'
FROM NotasItens
INNER JOIN NotasFiscais
  ON NFEmpresa = ItEmpresa
  AND NFNumero = ItNfNumero
  AND NFTIPO = ItTipo
INNER JOIN Tributos
  ON TribEmpresa = ItEmpresa
  AND TribCodigo = ItCFO
WHERE ItEmpresa = '03'
AND ItProduto = 'JKIT'
AND NFDtEmis >= '2016-04-01'
AND NFDtEmis <= '2017-07-31'
AND NFStatus = 'I'
AND NFTipo = 'S'
AND NFEmpresa = '03'
AND UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(TribTpCFOP))) = 'VENDA'
GROUP BY YEAR(NFDtEmis),
         MONTH(NFDtEmis),
         ItProduto,
--       ItQtde /* invalido no group by */
ORDER BY YEAR(NFDtEmis), MONTH(NFDtEmis)
```

Answer (score 2):

Se quer agrupar por mês você precisa selecionar apenas as colunas referentes no `group by`, sem agrupar pela quantidade:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(NFDtEmis) AS 'Ano',
  MONTH(NFDtEmis) AS 'Mes',
  ItProduto AS 'Produto',
  SUM(ItQtde) AS 'Quantidade total'
FROM NotasItens
INNER JOIN NotasFiscais
  ON NFEmpresa = ItEmpresa
  AND NFNumero = ItNfNumero
  AND NFTIPO = ItTipo
INNER JOIN Tributos
  ON TribEmpresa = ItEmpresa
  AND TribCodigo = ItCFO
WHERE ItEmpresa = '03'
AND ItProduto = 'JKIT'
AND NFDtEmis >= '2016-04-01'
AND NFDtEmis <= '2017-07-31'
AND NFStatus = 'I'
AND NFTipo = 'S'
AND NFEmpresa = '03'
AND UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(TribTpCFOP))) = 'VENDA'
GROUP BY YEAR(NFDtEmis),
         MONTH(NFDtEmis),
         ItProduto
ORDER BY YEAR(NFDtEmis), MONTH(NFDtEmis)
```

**detalhe**: o agrupamento pela quantidade (`ItQtde`) vai agrupar na linha apenas quando ela for igual; ou seja, se você tem quantidades diferentes na venda do mesmo produto, ele não somará na mesma linha e criará uma linha para cada. Ex: duas vendas de 10 produtos e duas vendas de 50; o *select* traria duas linhas, uma com total 20 e outra com total 100.